# Is there native support to create a Maven BOM in Gradle 5?

Tags: gradle

I've used Spring's dependency management plugin until now to create and publish a BOM. Starting with Gradle 5 BOM import is natively supported but can I also create BOMs easily without using a 3rd party plugin ?

Comment: What kind of "BOM" are you talking about? "Byte Order Mark" for UTF-8 encoded files? "Bill Of Material" for invoicing? "Browser Object Model" for a web browser?

Comment: Bill of Material. Like used in Maven